# How to resolve dependencies when compiling a software from source

Tags: compiling

What are the best tools for resolving unmet dependencies when compiling from source? I read about 'apt-file' and 'checkinstall' from ubuntu documentation however i just can't seem to install these two(2) packages in the terminal with sudo apt-get install  command or through synaptic package manager or software centre. Thanks in advance

Comment: why can't you install those packages?  Are there errors?

Comment: Well terminal reports that those packages can't be found

Comment: maybe you don't have the universe repository installed?  You may find `apt-cache policy (package)` useful.  It tells you whether the package is installable.

Comment: Got the packages now all i had to do was a sudo apt-get update after enabling all the repos in the software sources. Can you throw more light weight the your apt-cache policy command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo apt-get build-dep (package)`

That should install all the packages needed to build something.  You may also need to install `build-essentials`

Comment: Already installed build essentials but still can't those two packages. I'll try the build-dep later and report