# Cannot compile from source: "CMake Warning", "Add the installation prefix of X to CMake_PREFIX_PATH"

Tags: package-management, compiling

So before I continue bloating my new installation of KDE Neon with unnecessary stuff, I thought I'd ask the sub for some answers:

I am on KDE Neon 5.10 (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) and I am trying to compile the Latte Dock from source/install it via the install.sh ... When I run the script, it will fail and give me the above mentioned warning of "CMake Warning", "Add the installation prefix of X to CMake_PREFIX_PATH", where X used to be anything fro CMake itself, to qt5, to libqt5 and now its currently at KF5Wayland Icon themes.

I have resolved any of these dependencies by installing the packages via Synaptic, but my question is if that is the right way? Is the installation missing something that should be available by default? Other bash install scripts work (e.g. Pycharm), but this one and other extensions give me a special headache.

Would be great if you could advice if I should continue to install one *-dev package after the next, or if there is a better solution

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So essentially you're asking [How do I find the dependencies when building software from source?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172367/how-do-i-find-the-dependencies-when-building-software-from-source) or [How to resolve dependencies when compiling a software from source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33546/how-to-resolve-dependencies-when-compiling-a-software-from-source)?

Comment: My apologies, I am asking for neither. I want to know if these kinds of issues indicate a larger repository that is missing that needs to be installed, or if I really do have to go through the errors 1by1 and install the packages it demands.

Comment: If a needed repository were missing, you would not be able to install the packages at all. Possibly what you are thinking of is a *development metapackage* for Neon similar to `xorg-dev` for X Windows?